# Why insert/create does not work in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

**SQL Dump is:**

```
   CREATE TABLE `visitors` (
  `idVisitor` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


ALTER TABLE `visitors`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`idVisitor`);


ALTER TABLE `visitors`
  MODIFY `idVisitor` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=9;
COMMIT;
```

**Full model is:**

```
class Visitor extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    public $table = 'visitors';

    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    protected $primaryKey = 'idVisitor';


    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope(new StatusScope);
    }

    public function checker()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id', 'user_checked');
    }

    public function event()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Event', 'idEvent', 'idEvent');

    }
}
```

**Insert is:**

```
$c = Visitor::create(["name" => "4"]);

 echo json_encode($c);die();
```

It returns: `{"name":"4","idVisitor":8}`, but in table there is not inserted row. I dont use transactions.

Comment: I wrapped whole code in try/catch, but no exceptions

Comment: `idVisitor` is `NOT NULL` and not `AUTO_INCREMENT`, so you should give it a value

Comment: Yes, I fix it, but it is still does not work

Comment: I have edited question

Comment: you binded lastname to an integer but is declared as varchar

Comment: No matter it is string `1`

Comment: Not in the code you posted

Comment: I have fixed this too

Comment: Check my question, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your model I think you need to set the $fillable var.  you would place all the attributes in that car that you will be insert/updating.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent See the mass assignment section.

Comment: Okay, I will try to list all fields in `$fillable `

Comment: No, it also has no effect

Comment: Can be this reason: `ENGINE=InnoDB` ?

Comment: I have simplified table, check question